# Falling Objects Corona

Tags: algorithm, timer, coronasdk

I am trying to create a falling objects game. However, I am having hard time to create level for this game. It does not change scene or anything but I want it to be harder along the way. There are bad and good items falling and the character should eat good items and avoid from bad items.

I am creating those bad and good items with a createItem function and calling this function with two timer.performWithDelay. The items are falling randomly. One for the good items and one for the bad items. However, sometimes bad item comes under the good item and it is impossible to catch the good item. How can I stop that? I added a collision filter to let those items pass through each other so that's why they come as one under the another.

Here is how I call createItem with two timers:

```
 goodTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, function() createItem(goodItem[math.random(1,#goodItem)],1) end, 0 )

 badTimer = timer.performWithDelay(5000, function()  createItem(badItem[math.random(1,#badItem)],0) end, 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a deterministic behaviour (e.g., always having the option to get a good item), you would have to re-define the random layout such that it cannot affect this behaviour in any case. From your description, you are just taking collisions into account, what does not represent an accurate correction for pure randomness.

In this situation, I would:

- set up a "security area" surrounding each item. For example: 2
  times height/width of the given item.
- make the generation of each item depend on other (existing) items. For example: before creating a good item, your algorithm should check if there is already an existing bad one which might interfere with it. That is, if, by bringing the aforementioned security area into account, there is any chance that both items would be in a situation you don't want. This analysis should be easily performed by calculating the expected collision point of the corresponding security areas under the current velocities. In case of finding out that a collision might occur, the generation of the item would be delayed, completely ignored or its type might be changed (from bad to good or vice versa).
- set the collision rules but just as an in-the-safest-side post-correction, as far as most of the situations should be accounted for by the aforementioned points.